# In place std::move in pubsub

Tags: c++, move, google-cloud-pubsub, move-semantics

In pubsub google official documentation https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull we can find such example.

```
namespace pubsub = ::google::cloud::pubsub;
auto sample = [](pubsub::Subscriber subscriber) {
  return subscriber.Subscribe(
      [&](pubsub::Message const& m, pubsub::AckHandler h) {
        std::cout << "Received message " << m << "\n";
        std::move(h).ack();
        PleaseIgnoreThisSimplifiesTestingTheSamples();
      });
};
```

I am curious why `std::move` is used here. As I understand the only thing that `std::move` does is to cast an object to rvalue. I do not see any difference if it is used here or not. I would appreciate if someone could explain this.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you why this is the way it is, but the reason for the call to `std::move` is that `pubsub::AckHandler::ack` is declared as `void ack() &&` and the trailing `&&` means that the function can only be called on rvalues.  Since `h` is an lvalue, they used `std::move` to cast it back to an rvalue expression so that `ack` could be called.

Comment: My interpretation of the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/cpp/google-cloud-pubsub/latest/classgoogle_1_1cloud_1_1pubsub_1_1v1_1_1AckHandler.html) is that this is an attempt to encode at the language level that only one of `ack()` or `nack()` should be called on a given instance.  I.e. once you called `ack()`, the object is "gone".

Comment: What Frank said above.  You can only call `ack()` or `nack()`, and only once.  Some compilers will warn you if you do something like `std::move(h).ack(); std::move(h).ack();` and we wanted to take advantage of the warning.

Comment: @coryan FWIW, `ack(std::move(h));` would be a lot more intuitive for the programmer. It makes it clear that "ownership" is being handed-off.