# Is there any advantage to moving a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, move-semantics

I'm working with a code base right now, and there's this section that has the following:

```
if(const auto *temp_ptr = obj->get_ptr()) {
  perm_ptr = std::move(temp_ptr);
}
```

What is the point of the `std::move` in this case when it's just a simple pointer? It doesn't seem there's any advantage over simply doing `perm_ptr = temp_ptr`?

Comment: No advantage.  It seems that the author doesn't know what `std::move` does.

Comment: @DrewDormann Are there any downsides to doing this?

Comment: Nope!  `std::move` makes the pointer an r-value.  And the pointer, being an r-value, makes no difference.

Comment: @user5965026 it confuses readers of the code, just like `perm_ptr = static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(temp_ptr)>::type&&>(temp_ptr);` would

Comment: I could actually see a case where this could be intentional: if `perm_ptr` was some kind of homebrew `unique_ptr` with a `operator=(T*&&)` operator to make it clear at the callsite that ownership is being transfered from a raw pointer into the owning pointer. It's an abuse of the syntax, but there are similar precedents for this kind of thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69213032/in-place-stdmove-in-pubsub/69213082#comment122331811_69213082

Comment: If `perm_ptr` is also a raw pointer, then `std::move()` makes no sense here. But if `perm_ptr` is some kind of object with an overloaded `operator=` that takes a raw pointer, then `std::move()` *might* make sense, as it would allow `operator=` to reset the raw pointer after copying it.

Answer (score 3):

As said in the comments, if the type of `perm_ptr` is a raw pointer type, then the move is pointless.

However, it is possible to define a type for `perm_ptr` that would make this syntax *meaningful*. Whether it would be useful is at best highly debatable, and results in unintuitive and unconventional code.

It involves defining an assignment operator that only accepts a RValue to a pointer. Like so: `operator=(T*&& p);`.

This could, for instance, be used to ensure that no one accidentally assigns a raw pointer to something that will eventually calling `delete` on it without doing so intentionally.

It could also be used to reset the pointer to `nullptr` (or some other value) as part of the assignment.

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
struct my_unique_ptr {
  ~my_unique_ptr() {
    if(ptr_) delete ptr_;
  }

  my_unique_ptr& operator=(T*&& p) { 
    ptr_ = p; 
    p = nullptr;
    return *this; 
  }

private:
  T* ptr_ = nullptr;
};

int main() {
    my_unique_ptr<int> perm_ptr ;

    int* ptr = new int;

// all good.
    owning_ptr = std::move(ptr);

// compile error!
    owning_ptr = ptr;  

}
```

To be 100% clear: This is a only an example that could result in the program presented by the OP being intentional and meaningful. I am not advocating for such a technique. Even if it was a good idea, it would still  be fraught with caveats and pitfalls that are not being covered by this answer.